# Vassal-like dice for chat-sessions

Tags: dice, online-roleplaying

I recently played a game on the board-game simulator Vassal that simulated the game's custom d6s. I'm wondering if anybody knows of a similar program (or even a module for vassal) that lets a group share customized die rolls with each other in real time over the internet.

What I would prefer is a format where each player has their own window and their dice appear within it when they roll.

I tried http://dicelog.com/dice but Firefox warns me that the site is not secure...

Comment: Firefox is just warning that the security certificate isn't from a recognized SSL certificate provider. Given you're using this for rolling dice, I wouldn't worry about it. You wouldn't want to hand over your credit card, but it is no less secure than any other site you might use.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of "custom d6s" you mean. Are these dice with different numbering (e.g. a d6 with 1,1,1,4,6,6), or dice with pictographs (e.g. ⚔,⚔,⚔,⚡,⚡,☠)? Or…?

Comment: in that case it was the Arkham dice with a special symbol for the 6.

Answer (score 1):

The module for [Dungeons and Dragons miniatures](http://www.vassalengine.org/wiki/Module%3aDungeons_&_Dragons_Miniatures) might suffice.

Comment: Hi @World Engineer, welcome to RPG.SE!  Could you expand your answer to include a little more about the site your recommending?  A feature list or screenshot would be excellent.